# COB LEDs for Flood Light

Tags: voltage, led, light, cob

I am using luminus CXM-18 COB.

The specifications in the [Data Sheet](http://www.luminus.com/products/Luminus_XnovaCXM18-GEN1_Datasheet.pdf) read a minimum current of 800mA and max 1550mA  at 800mA the power I get will be 29W and at 1550mA it is 65W while the voltage  is 33.5V typical.

I am using two COBs on the same housing while I am using a driver with following specifications voltage is 28-36V current: 700mA it still works but on a lower power output.

I have connected the COBs on a two different drivers. Now while I place the LEDs on the housing it works for about 2 minutes max then either one or both disconnect the soldered wire and once I experienced flickering of COB after working for 45 seconds.

What could be the reason behind this and how do I make it work properly? I have a heat sink and applied a scapa thermal tape thickness 15mm.

The heat sink is for 100W and can the way of soldering be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either the LED you have is not the one described in the datasheet and you are overloading it with current, either your thermal contact between the LED and heatsink is poor and you cannot radiate the power. Flickering of the LED if the driver is OK occurs when a LED is *partially* blown up.

For the wire to desolder its temperature should be more than 200-240 degrees Celsius, while LEDs can work properly to only 65-70 deg. Celsius. If a wire melts its solder and detaches you can throw this LED to junk.

Get a variable current source (bench power supply) and a Lux meter. Power up the LED (placed on a good heatsink of course) with some small current and look at the Lux meter's readings. Slowly increase current till you see that more current does not increase Luxes significantly. That is the maximum current you would want to drive into this LED. I would suggest using it with about 50-60% of this current to get more efficiency - Lumen per Watt.

Comment: Hello Todor, this is helpful well I did not screw down the COB holder to the heat sink, while it could be a lose contact between the heat sink and the LED could the current be an issue since I am using 700mA driver while the minimum it requires is 800mA. It surely provides less current so current should not be the issue I still have a doubt on this. And I am not using a lead free solder wire could that be a reason the wire gets desoldered?

Comment: @NiharPatel, the solder should not be a problem, because any solder melts at temperature much higher than a LED can withstand.

Comment: How about the current supply being lower than minimum will it affect?

Comment: @NiharPatel lower current wont do any harm - LED will produce less light AND less heat.

Comment: Shall I mail you the images of LED and heat sink and the driver I am using?

Comment: If you don't make some measurements as I suggested, I don't think I could be in any help just by pictures.

Comment: Okay, I shall run the tests.